# How to read the first column with its values in excel as a columns names in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

So first of all I have an Excel file with a lot of sheets, now there's some of sheets that look like this:

```
|    Date    | 11-12-2019  | 12-12-2019   | 13-12-2019 | 14-12-2019  | 15-12-2019   |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| Col_1      |    1111     |     2222     | 3333       |        4444 |     5555     |
| Col_2      |    1111     |     2222     | 3333       |        4444 |     5555     |
| Col_3      |    1111     |     2222     | 3333       |        4444 |     5555     |
| Col_4      |    1111     |     2222     | 3333       |        4444 |     5555     |
| Col_5      |    1111     |     2222     | 3333       |        4444 |     5555     |
| Col_6      |    1111     |     2222     | 3333       |        4444 |     5555     |
```

I want to make it with pandas data frame to be something like this:

```
|    Date    |    Col_1    |     Col_2    | Col_3      |   Col_4     |     Col_5    |     Col_5    |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:------------:|
| 11-12-2019 |    1111     |     1111     | 1111       |    1111     |     1111     |     1111     |
| 12-12-2019 |    2222     |     2222     | 2222       |    2222     |     2222     |     2222     |
| 13-12-2019 |    3333     |     3333     | 3333       |    3333     |     3333     |     3333     |
| 14-12-2019 |    4444     |     4444     | 4444       |    4444     |     4444     |     4444     |
| 15-12-2019 |    5555     |     5555     | 5555       |    5555     |     5555     |     5555     |
```

So is it possible to do this with python pandas or any other libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this using `Transpose` (same as [`DataFrame.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html)). Then replacing the column names by first row using [`DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
dft = df.T                  # transpose dataframe
dft.columns = dft.iloc[0]   # replace columns, by values in first row
dft = dft.iloc[1:]          # remove first row.
```

```
Date       Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 Col_4 Col_5 Col_6
11-12-2019  1111  1111  1111  1111  1111  1111
12-12-2019  2222  2222  2222  2222  2222  2222
13-12-2019  3333  3333  3333  3333  3333  3333
14-12-2019  4444  4444  4444  4444  4444  4444
15-12-2019  5555  5555  5555  5555  5555  5555
```

Comment: Thanks for your support I think I need some thing like this, I'll accept your answr as well.... It's seems to be right!!! :D thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

you can also use [df.swapaxes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swapaxes.html?highlight=swapax)

```
>>> df.set_index('Date').swapaxes(1,0)

Date        Col_1  Col_2  Col_3  Col_4  Col_5  Col_6
11-12-2019   1111   1111   1111   1111   1111   1111
12-12-2019   2222   2222   2222   2222   2222   2222
13-12-2019   3333   3333   3333   3333   3333   3333
14-12-2019   4444   4444   4444   4444   4444   4444
15-12-2019   5555   5555   5555   5555   5555   5555
```

Comment: I love these pandas hidden gems

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially do this with the Python library/Excel add-in xlwings. Code would be something like this:

```
import xlwings as xw
sht = xw.Book().sheets[0]
pd_df = sht.range('reference to cells with data').options(transpose = True, pd.DataFrame, index = True, header = True).value
```